Pybind include file not found in Python library written in C/C++
I'm working on a Python library written using C/C++. Here is a general idea of the structure.
name/ 
│ 
├── bindings/ 
├── src/ │   
         ├── cpp/   
         ├── c/ 
         │     
         └── include/ 
├── build/ │   
           ├── Makefile 
├── tests/ 
├── CMakeLists.txt 


In bindings, I have a file to bind each method to the Python library, here is an example
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include "../src/include/method.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(name, m) {
    m.doc() = "Description";
    m.def("method", &method, "Documentation header",
          py::arg("arg1") ...);
}


However, in the first line #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>, it throws the following error.
/usr/local/include/pybind11/pybind11.h


In included file: 'Python.h' file not foundclang(pp_file_not_found)

When I build the project and test out the Python module however, it works fine. Thats why I think the error has something to do with my vscode configuration. Any idea what this means and how I can fix it (if I even need to) ?
I tried to add a .vscode directory and in my project and added the following file titled c_cpp_properties.json.
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/include",
            "/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}


I think it is because the C compiler cant locate the python header files, which will be needed to compile the code that goes along with pybind11.
What are you using to edit the code? Virtual Studio Code?
I had this issue, this worked for me:

Make sure the py dev headers are installed.
If you are using VSC, make sure that the c json file has the path to where the py headers are located. I believe the json file is 'c_cpp_properties.json'.
Then try to close and reopen VSC, and rebuild after you have made changes to the c json file.
Try to restart and rebuild the project.

I also found that if custom py installations or other virtual environments are installed, make sure that the environment variables are set to the py installation that match the headers.
